# How can I create ASP class with "To" property (like CDONTS.NewMail)?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

The CDONTS.NewMail class let's me send email like this:

```
Set MailObj = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")
MailObj.To = someone@example.com
' set other properties of MailObj
MailObj.Send
```

I can create my own class in ASP, but it won't let me define a property named "To".

Is there some way I can create a class with a property named "To" in a class that I define?

```
class MyMail
  Public To          ' this doesn't work!
  Public From        ' this works great!
end class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to mark the identifier with []. As in:

```
Option Explicit

Class cC
  Public [To]
End Class

Dim oC : Set oC = New cC
oC.To = 4711
Dim i
For i = 0 To 1
    WScript.Echo oC.To
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 36585334.vbs
4711
4711
```

(See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81ed9a62%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for 'escaped names'/[] in another Basic dialect.)

Comment: Thanks... that's awesome! Works perfect.